# fetch data from one table and insert then into another table Mysql, Sidekiq, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, sidekiq

We have to fetch around 5 millions of records from one table and insert them into another table with same table structure.

We are using Sidekiq and redis to put the records to be inserted in the queue and insert from the queue.

Here is my code :
`User_controller` :

```
def reinsert_users    
   @active_users = ExportUser.all
   RecreateUserWorker.perform_async(@active_users)
end
```

`recreateuser_worker.rb` :

```
class RecreateUserWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(users)
    begin     
      @user = User.new("true")
      @user.recreate(users)
    rescue
      raise
    end
  end

end
```

'''''

```
User.rb :

def recreate(users)
    users.each do |user|
      @user = ExportUsersV2.new(user)  # new table to insert
      @user.save     
    end
end
```

This is the error i get :

```
WARN: {"class"=>"RecreateUserWorker", "args"=>["#<ExportUser::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xa3781b0>"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"25fe4378de1bb967ff4d1e5e", "enqueued_at"=>1438605202.8414373, "error_message"=>"undefined method `each' for \"#<ExportUser::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xa3781b0>\":String", "error_class"=>"NoMethodError", "failed_at"=>1438605202.8470101, "retry_count"=>0}
```

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in a complex Ruby object, which is not allowed.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to insert users in bulks using direct mysql queries.

You can use gem https://github.com/tauqeer-ahmad/bulk_uploadable/tree/master or any other gem for this.

I think this may resolve this issue.

Comment: Is bulk_uploadable gem is good enough to insert 3-4 millions of records in one shot?? Is it asynchronous process?? if any record is not inserted due to some reason then how do we track failed records??